# How can I improve this taxonomy treating approach?

Tags: categories, templates, taxonomy

I want to list subcategories of certain parent category in my template `category-id.php` with followed code

```
function the_categories_navigations_trees() {

  $cat_data = get_categories( 
          array ( 
              'parent' => 42, 
              'hide_empty' => 0 
          ) 
      );

  if ( $cat_data ) {
       $cat_links = '';
       foreach ( $cat_data as $one_cat_data)
         $cat_links .= sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a><br/>', 
         get_category_link( $one_cat_data->term_id ) , $one_cat_data->cat_name );
         printf( '<div class="nav-cat">%s</div>', $cat_links ); 
  }
}
```

The problem is that I need to duplicate this function for all categories/subcategories which have children, only replacing a category id.
It is overhead, really.

So, how can I optimize my approach. May be there is some method to use one and only one function for all templates to list subcategories.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This is what functions.php is for. Add the function to functions.php, with just a slight modification that will allow you to pass in which category you want to get the children of:

```
function the_categories_navigations_trees( $parent ) {
    $cat_data = get_categories( array( 
        'parent'     => $parent, 
        'hide_empty' => 0 
    ) );

    if ( $cat_data ) {
        $cat_links = '';

        foreach ( $cat_data as $one_cat_data) {
            $cat_links .= sprintf( 
                '<a href="%s">%s</a><br/>',
                get_category_link( $one_cat_data->term_id ),
                $one_cat_data->cat_name
            );
        }

        printf( '<div class="nav-cat">%s</div>', $cat_links ); 
    }
}
```

See the `$parent` argument in the function?

Now in your template you can use this to get the output for a particular parent:

```
<?php the_categories_navigations_trees( get_queried_object_id() ); ?>
```

`get_queried_object_id()` will get the ID of the category you're currently viewing. Replace it with something specific if you need to.